# How can I keep colouring when piping man to less?

Tags: zsh, colors, man, less

I have this in my `.zshrc` file

```
export MANLESS=""
export LESS="--RAW-CONTROL-CHARS"
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$(tput bold; tput setaf 5)
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$(tput bold; tput setaf 1)
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$(tput setaf 1; tput setab 3)
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$(tput rmso; tput sgr0)
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$(tput setaf 3)
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$(tput sgr0)
```

When I use man as: `man zshexpn`, I have nicely colored sections:

[image]

When I use man as: `man zshexpn | less '+/PROCESS SUBSTITUTION'`, on same part of the manual page, it is no longer colored:

[image]

How can I get colored output in second case, same as first case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of piping through `less` with extra options, pass those extra options in the `LESS` variable.

```
LESS="$LESS +/PROCESS SUBSTITUTION" man zshexpn
```

Answer (score 17):

I’m assuming you’re using `man` on a mainstream Linux distribution. `man` there (and on other systems) defaults to removing formatting if its output isn’t a terminal; since you’re manually piping to `less`, that’s what’s happening here.

You can override this by setting `MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING` to a non-empty value:

```
MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING=1 man zshexpn | less '+/PROCESS SUBSTITUTION'
```

If you want this behaviour to be the default, export `MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING` along with your other settings; bear in mind that this will affect all `man` invocations, which will have side-effects when the output *doesn’t* end up being processed by a terminal (*e.g.* if you want to `grep` the output).

Comment: I have discovered a problem with exporting `MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING=1`. When I do `man zshexpn | grep -n 'FILENAME GENERATION'`, grep finds only one match, whereas without the option grep finds 2 matches.

Comment: @400theCat Yeah, that's kinda expected and the main reason `man` (and many other programs) disable generating terminal escape sequences when not writing to a terminal. You would have to design your regex to silently skip any terminal escape codes (which would make it really complex) or pipe through another intermediate step to strip out all escape sequences. It's probably much easier to just define a shell function for the `man something | less` combination which will internally set `MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING`.